# Node JS EWS CreateAttachment failing due to XML parsing error

Tags: json, node.js, xml, soap, exchangewebservices

I am trying to attach a file in EWS using Node JS but I keep getting the error:
**The request failed schema validation: Name cannot begin with the '0' character, hexadecimal value 0x30**

I've read online that it could be related to some spaces in the XML namespace (since EWS uses SOAP) but as you can see, in the following method below, I am using JSON format (which is translated by **node-ews module** into XML at a lower level) so I doubt it's a malformed request unless there is a bug in node-ews (because other requests work just fine - it's just the file attachment that's failing)! Any help would be appreciated.

```
function createAttachment(id, changeKey, fileName, content) {

  var ewsFunction = 'CreateAttachment';
  var ewsArgs = {
    'ParentItemId': {
      'attributes': {
        'Id': id,
        'ChangeKey': changeKey
      }
    },
    'Attachments': {
      'FileAttachment': {
        'Name': fileName,
        'Content': content
      }
    }
  }

  return ews.run(ewsFunction, ewsArgs)
            .then(result => {
              return result.ResponseMessages.CreateAttachmentResponseMessage.Attachments.FileAttachment.AttachmentId;
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err.message));

}
```

Hisham

Comment: Have you been able to solve the problem yet? I'm getting the same error when trying to do "UpdateItem"

Comment: Yes, fixed now. I used to pass a buffer as content (Buffer.from(b64string, 'base64') so it used to fail. I am now passing the b64string itself as content without converting it to Buffer. It could be something else in your case (if you're having an issue) but there's high chance it's the content format.

Comment: Thank you. I won't have access to that machine or exchange server till monday but I'll let you know if that solved the problem.

Comment: Alright - please do :)

Comment: OK. I was not able to reproduce it. But not so much because it's not the content format but because I just don't know how to send the different content formats.

Comment: Okay, by "not able to reproduce it", do you mean you're no longer having that issue? If that's not what you meant, feel free to explain the issue here or start a new thread and kindly point me to it so I can contribute.

Comment: No. I'm still having the issue. Worked around with a ternary operator for every attribute. I just have no idea how to do what you did with passing Buffer and Content. I also openend an issue in github, since this problem only seems to happen with this specific function in my case.(https://github.com/CumberlandGroup/node-ews/issues/66)